# ion java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, image, imageview, classcastexception, android-ion

I'm using ION (https://github.com/koush/ion) to load images from the web into a `ListView` of `ImageView`. Currently I want to get the bitmap from the `ImageView`, but I'm getting one exception that is force closing my app:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.koushikdutta.ion.IonDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

These are the lines that I'm using:

```
final ImageView itemImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.photoImage);
final Bitmap itemDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) itemImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line. `final Bitmap itemDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) itemImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Comment: @ShivamVerma I'm trying to get the bitmap of the ImageView, but BitmapDrawable can't be casted to IonDrawable.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve. This might not be the best method of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you consider to use volley's imageloader?
I found it really easy to use and you can cast it to a bitmap with no problem.
Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) and [this](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader) tutorials if you are interested

Comment: Ion sets a custom drawable, so it can't be cast to a BitmapDrawable.

Use:
Ion.with(imageView).getBitmap()
to get the bitmap out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth looking into:

[**nostra13's "Universal Image Loader"**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

It's an awesome library with tons of features to display images from URLs, cast to bitmaps, etc.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem! Took 5min to replace everything!

Comment: @Jonny07  : Can you let me know is it possible to convert and XML (has an imageView) to Bitmap in UniversalImageLoader? I am trying out the following: http://goo.gl/1hs4bn - My question on SO: http://goo.gl/Sz2fV0 But picasso doesn't load image properly I sometimes get the image or placeholder image. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Ion sets a custom drawable to manage animated GIFs, fade transitions, etc, so it can't be cast to a BitmapDrawable.

Use:

```
Ion.with(imageView).getBitmap()
```

to get the bitmap out

Answer (score 3):

If you set a callback when making the Ion request and have it return an ImageViewBitmapInfo you can retrieve bitmaps that way. For e.g.

```
Ion.with(imageView)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
   .load(userImageURL)
   .withBitmapInfo()
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<ImageViewBitmapInfo>() {
       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Exception e, ImageViewBitmapInfo result) {
           // Check for exceptions

           // Check bitmaps first
           Bitmap b = result.getBitmapInfo().bitmaps[0];
           ...
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(imageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable)
    bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
else { /***to check if it is ION drawable, use ION*/
    bm = Ion.with(imageView).getBitmap();
}
```